# JSon parsing with JQuery and ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I am a beginner with JQuery and I want to Write jQuery script to make an ajax call to the URL

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=falls&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?

I want to display the title and link of the 1st five items read.

Comment: You will find thousands of threads that answer this

Comment: Can you please post the code for what you have tried yet? and we can then solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function, the JSON is automatically parsed. How you want to display them is up to you. For example:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=falls&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    function (data) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            $('<a href="' + data.items[i].link + '">' +  data.items[i].title + '</a><br>').appendTo(document.body);
        }
    }
);
```

If you are showing many more, or more than just links, it would be wise to consider templating.

Comment: nice spoon feeding :)

Comment: @L1010 - quite right, not sure how I missed that, edited